# Why can't we use DTrace in iOS

Tags: ios, iphone, ios7, dtrace

Can we DTrace in iOS world? I tried using DTrace in my mac. Is there any way or APIs to achieve
DTrace things on iOS world?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

DTrace is not available in iOS but you can use it in the simulator. Look to this excellent articles witch explains it better.

[DTrace bignerdranch blog](http://www.bignerdranch.com/blog/hooked-on-dtrace-part-1/)